# Imagick::thumbnailImage not accepting 4 parameters when it used to

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagick

I've recently made some changes on a codeigniter app i maintain, and had to add a new thumbnail size for it's users.

So basically the original code looked like this.

```
$pic_thumb = new Imagick($targetFile);
$pic_thumb->thumbnailImage(40,40,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$pic_thumb->writeImage($thumbnail . $newf_name);
$thumbnail_file = $thumbnail . $newf_name;
$pic_thumb->destroy();
```

And i just added a new block to create the new thumbnail pic. And it worked perfectly on my production development server. After moving it to production, i saw that thumbnails weren't scaling. so i checked the logs and i saw this:

```
PHP Warning:  Imagick::thumbnailimage() expects at most 3 parameters, 4 given
```

There hasn't been any software update or changes, except that app and even restoring the previous version drops that error, and even the documentation shows it can accept up to 4 parameters.

```
bool Imagick::thumbnailImage ( int $columns , int $rows [, bool $bestfit = false [, bool $fill = false ]] )
```

If i do something like

```
    $pic_thumb->thumbnailImage(40,40,0);
```

Works, but i don't get the same effect since fill is disabled.

Btw the server is running Php 5.3.2

Can someone throw me some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Version of the Imagick-extension, the fill-parameter is available since [3.0.0b1](http://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=imagick&version=3.0.0b1)

Comment: Oh snap, thank you, yep you're right, seems the previous dev left me a custom built version of it, i guess i'll need to get in touch with him, since there's no doc about it. However i don't get why it worked earlier if no one changed that